# Delay runnables and terminate immediately after terminate() call

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

How can I delay the runnables (to change the background color) but be able to terminate the handler immediately after terminate() is called from the Activity?

```
public void handleBackgroundChange() {
    while(i != -1) {
        if(method.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.RGB_and_White))) {
            mHandler.post(r1);
        } else if (method.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.Black_and_White))) {
            mHandler.post(r2);
        } else if (method.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.White))) {
            mView.setBackgroundResource(colors.get(3));
        }
        SystemClock.sleep(duration.longValue());
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
  handleBackgroundChange();
}

public void terminate() {
    i = -1;
}

Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (i != -1) {
            mView.setBackgroundResource(colors.get(i));
            i++;
            if (i == 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};

Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (i != -1) {
            mView.setBackgroundResource(bw.get(i));
            i++;
            if (i == 2) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Background info: I am currently fixing an application (a screen burn-in fixer) I made a couple of months ago. The code below is working, but the handler takes long to terminate, especially when the duration is long. I know what's causing it (the SystemClock.sleep(...)) has to finish before the while loop will check i again, but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You should boil down your question to the actual point "how can I delay ..."

Comment: Rule of thumb: do not ever sleep on the UI thread. Users don't like it

Comment: I know I shouldn't use sleep on a UI thread, but I want to know what I should use instead.

Comment: can you not use wait and notify. If you want this method to run on a particular event you can wait till that event happens